# R creating new column based on split column name

Tags: r

I faced a problem while trying to re-arrange by data frame into long format.
my table looks like this:

```
x <- data.frame("Accession"=c("AGI1","AGI2","AGI3","AGI4","AGI5","AGI6"),"wt_rep_1"=c(1,2,3,4,4,5), "wt_rep_2" = c(1,2,3,4,8,9), "mutant1_rep_1"=c(1,1,0,0,5,3), "mutant2_rep_1" = c(1,7,0,0,1,5), "mutant2_rep_2" = c(1,1,4,0,1,8) )

> x
  Accession wt_rep_1 wt_rep_2 mutant1_rep_1 mutant2_rep_1 mutant2_rep_2
1      AGI1        1        1             1             1             1
2      AGI2        2        2             1             7             1
3      AGI3        3        3             0             0             4
4      AGI4        4        4             0             0             0
5      AGI5        4        8             5             1             1
6      AGI6        5        9             3             5             8
```

I need to create a column that I would name "genotype", and it would containt the first part of the name of the column before "_"
How to use
    `strsplit(names(x), "_")`
for that?
and preferably loop...
please, anyone, help.

Comment: Try with `sub` i.e. `sub("_.*", "", names(x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll extract the part of the column names of `x` before the first `_` in two instructions. Note that it can be done in just one line, but I'm posting like this for clarity.

```
sp <- strsplit(names(x), "_")
sapply(sp[-1], `[`, 1)
```

Now, how can this be a new column in `data.frame` `x`? There are only five elements in the resulting vector and `x` has six rows.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ruy Barradas: I don't get how this vector could be a part of your original dataframe. Could you please clarify?

William Doane's response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355355/how-to-avoid-a-loop-in-r-selecting-items-from-a-list) suggests that using regular expressions might do the trick. I like this approach because I find it elegant and fast:

```
  > gsub("(_.*)$", "", names(x))[-1]
  [1] "wt"      "wt"      "mutant1" "mutant2" "mutant2"
```

Comment: `> x_long
        Accession genotype replicate value
        1      AGI1       wt      rep1     1
        2      AGI1       wt      rep2     2
        3      AGI1  mutant1      rep1     3
        4      AGI1  mutant1      rep2     4`                                                                              long format is what I want finally achive. Thank you very much for your tips! I meant, in long format it's still the same table but transposed for later simplest navigation and use. More suggestions will be very, very wellcome.

Comment: sorry, I have formatting problem    x_long <- data.frame ("Accession" = c("AGI1", "AGI1", "AGI1", "AGI1"),"genotype" = c("wt", "wt", "mutant1", "mutant1"), "replicate" = c("rep1", "rep2", "rep1", "rep2"), "value" = c(1,2,3,4))
> x_long